# Getting the value at memory address X

Tags: c++, pointers, assembly, x86

I have a question: how can I see what is the value of the number at memory address X in c++.
I want to make something like the:

```
mov bx, 1024d
mov ax, [bx]
```

from assembly, where ax will be my result.

Thanks for the support.
P.S. I just started working with pointers and memory addresses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in c/c++ address is stored as pointer, so BX in your code in c++ will be

```
unsigned short* _mybx = (unsigned short*)1024U; // note casting to unsigned short*
```

to get value which is stored on address you need to use:

```
unsigned short _myax = *_mybx; // note asterix here
```

instead of c kind of cast, you can use reinterpret_cast

```
unsigned short* _bx = reinterpret_cast<unsigned short*>(1024);
```

which is more c++ way

Answer (score 6):

In C++, the value at that address is `*reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(1024)`.